# Array of undefined length of structures generates segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I am writing a compiler project. I created an AST tree, where every node is defined by structure:

```
typedef struct node {
   char type[10];
   char *string;
   int number_of_children;

   struct node *children[];
} node;
```

I wanted to create an array of symbols of undefined length. I created structure, to store name of the symbol and it's address in the memory:

```
typedef struct symbol {
   char *name;
   int address;
} symbol;
```

and then I created array of undefined length:

```
symbol *symbols_table[];
```

I created function to add new symbol:

```
void add_symbol(node *p) {
    symbols_table[number_of_symbols] = malloc(sizeof(symbol));
    symbols_table[number_of_symbols]->name = malloc(sizeof(p->string));

    strcpy(symbols_table[number_of_symbols]->name, p->string);
    symbols_table[number_of_symbols]->address = memory_pointer;

    memory_pointer++;
    number_of_symbols++;
}
```

where `p` is node from the AST tree and `memory_pointer` is needed to give address in the memory to each symbol.

And here is the problem. When I want to add only 2 symbols to the `symbols_table` everything is working fine. But when I want to add 3 and more it gives `segmentation fault`. Do you have any ideas, why is it happening?

Comment: What do you think the declaration `symbol *symbols_table[]` creates?   If you think it creates an array that can hold any number of elements you might choose to store in it, you are sadly mistaken.

Comment: I thought as you said. So this must be it. I have to change this array. Thank you very much :)

Comment: This definition `symbol *symbols_table[];`, if done globally, should make the compiler issue a warning, if given local to a function it should not even compile. Take warnings serious.

Answer (score 2):

The problem, as I see here is with

```
 symbols_table[number_of_symbols]->name = malloc(sizeof(p->string));
```

in your code, `string` is a pointer. So, `sizeof(p->string))` will not give you the size of the allocated memory, it will give you the size of the pointer itself. At later point, when you do `strcpy()` it overruns the allocated memory an creates [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

What you want instead is

```
 symbols_table[number_of_symbols]->name = malloc(strlen(p->string) + 1);
```

to get the proper memory allocation.

On a differnt approach, you can also have a look at [`strdup()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) to avoid the whole `malloc()` + `strcpy()` thing.

Comment: `+1`, although `strdup` is not standard C, so it depends on OP's platform whether they can use it or not.

Comment: @szczurcio Right. That is why I've put that as a note, rather. :)

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. I tried both solutions, but it didn't work :/ I don't think, that the problem is in the other part of program, but I may be wrong.